# Instalar plugin no Netbeans

Tags: android

Tentei instalar os plugins e não deu certo.
Eles estam visível na aba *definições*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém não se encontra na aba *Plug-ins* disponíveis. Eu cliquei inclusive para ser encontrado por ordem alfabética.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei encontra-lo através da busca, mas não consegui.

Instalei tudo que estava no *Android SDK Manager*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu for seguir adicionar o endereço http://kenai.com/downloads/nbandroid/updates.xml para instalar os plugins como está informando no site abaixo..

http://www.devmedia.com.br/integrando-o-sdk-android-ao-netbeans/15580

..ele vai gerar esse erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não é problema do firewall.

*Alguém pode me dizer o que houve de errado.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [wiki do nbandroid](http://nbandroid.org/wiki/index.php/Installation) o endereço **atual** e **correto** para instalar os plugins é:

```
http://nbandroid.org/release72/updates/updates.xml
```

Isso provavelmente vai resolver o problema.

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado.  :)